# How to await tasks based on condition?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to know if at least one of the results returned from `GetDataFromLongRunningOp` meets a certain condition:

```
foreach (var item in list)
{
    var result = GetDataFromLongRunningOp(item);
    if (CheckCondition(result))
    {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

How can I call `GetDataFromLongRunningOp` for each item in parallel, to reduce the total time needed to find the answer?

**Edit**: `GetDataFromLongRunningOp` is an async method.

Comment: I dont see any `Task` or any use of `await`. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `GetDataFromLongRunningOp` asynchronously using `Task.Run`. Use a `TaskCompletionSource` which will return a finished task when a result that meets the condition is returned. If no result meets the condition then `tcs.Task` will never finish. You need another task that waits for all the tasks to finish. So, in the end, you need to wait for either `tcs.Task` or `Task.WhenAll` to finish.

```
var result = false;

var tasks = new List<Task>();
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => GetDataFromLongRunningOp(item))
        .ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (CheckCondition(t.Result))
            {
                result = true;
                tcs.TrySetResult(true);
            }
        });
    tasks.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAny(tcs.Task, Task.WhenAll(tasks));

return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your work is CPU bound and not IO Bound, You can look into [`Parallel.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, (item) => 
{
    var result = GetDataFromLongRunningOp(item);
    if (CheckCondition(result))
    {
        return true;
    }
});

return false;
```

Note that you have to make sure `GetDataFromLongRunningOp` is thread-safe and of course, **benchmark** your code to make sure running this in parallel doesn't outweigh the cost.